# How to initialize a toggle button's selection state in a view's toolbarin an eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I contributed a toggle-style toolbar contribution to my view in my RCP. Now, i want to know how to set the button's state (since it's a toggle button) from my view. Or, at least, how to initialize it's state after the view is loaded (the toggle state can vary, its not static)

I tried to call from my view: getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager().getItems() (returns an array of IContributionElements), which i iterated over and looked for the id. but the array only contains the models of the buttons, and there is no possibility to change the selection through these objects.

Help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the definition of your command (in plug-in.xml) that the `CommandContributionItem`
calls into, define a state element like the following:

```
<state class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState:true"
     id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
</state>
```

The above will initialise the state (toggle on/off) to either true/false depending on what you specify after the 'RegistryToggleState:' section.

To change the state within your code, first get the reference to your `ParamterizedCommand` like you did before. Then get the reference to the underyling `Command`object from the `ParamaterizedCommmand` and call:

> ```
>  HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this pinpointed everything. Really precise and sharp, thanks again!

Comment: Addition: if anyone is wondering if its just possible to toggle the state of the menu item -- just look at the code in the HandlerUtil toggle method and adapt it.

Comment: Not that to visually update a contribution you must implement IElementUpdater and update the UI element in updateElement()

Comment: @Kemoda state is tied to command so if the state id is `org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState` then the toggle works on the commandmenu item. If you don't used the toggleState id then you have to set it yourself with updateElement as you say.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the item to `ActionContributionItem`, get the `Action` and call `setChecked()`:

```
((ActionContributionItem) item).getAction().setChecked(true);
```

Comment: My item is of the type CommandContributionItem. I can call getCommand() instead of getAction() (returning a ParameterizedCommand type), but then there are no methods that help me further

Comment: @simlei Ah, sorry - I'm using Actions in my toolbar, don't know how to do it with Commands

Answer (score 0):

To change the state to a specific one, try command.getState(), and state.setValue() methods, as shown in example:

```
private void refreshToggleButtonState(String commandID, String constantID) {

    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);  
    Command command = commandService.getCommand(commandID);  

    State state = command.getState(RegistryToggleState.STATE_ID);
    if (Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(constantID)) {
        state.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        state.setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}
```

constantID is a preference store parameter, assuming you have one.